# Number of subsets with no four elements satisfying $a+b=c+d$

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

Let $A=\{1,2,...,9\}$. We are going to find the number of subsets of $A$ with no four distinct elements satisfying $a+b=c+d$. Let $N$ be a positive integer such that it is possible to write it as sum of at least   two pairs of elements of $A$. Then $N$ ranges from $5$  to $15$.  One may use the inclusion-exclusion principle to find the number of desired subsets. However, this method  is too long and I think there would be an easier and faster way to do the problem.

please give a hint to find a  better way.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Does the question ask about the number of subsets that have exactly $4$ elements $\{ a,b,c,d \}$ for which we don't have $a +b=c+d$?

Comment: No. Any subset of the set with no such four elements.

Comment: Yikes ... looks nasty indeed. Nothing helpful immediately comes to my mind ...

Comment: You could first of all try counting the number of distinct solutions to $a+b=c+d$, that shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No complete answer, but this should help:

As soon as you have two pairs of successive numbers, the equation can clearly be made to work. So, there is no subset of size $7$ or larger for which there are no such $4$ elements.

You can also rule out subsets of size $6$. The only way to not get $2$ distinct pairs of successive numbers is to have $1,3,5,7,9$ plus one more number, but now obviously $1+7=3+5$

So, you 'only' need to check subsets of sizes $4$ and $5$

Comment: Thanks Bram28 this is nice as  reduces the problem to check the subsets of sizes 4 and 5. But you think is it possible to find a recusrive relation? (for $A=\{1,2,...,n\}$)